# Chart.js chart does not display when inside an ngIf.

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular, chart.js

I have a simple scatter line chart within a bootstrap panel created with Chart.js. It works/displays perfectly fine until I put it inside an ngIf div. Has anyone come across this? Any idea on how to make the chart display? The point of the `ngIf` in my example is to only show the `panel-body`'s content (which is the chart) once the variable `chartData` has been populated.

Here's my chart code (I've commented out the ngIf div):

```
<!--<div *ngIf="chartData.length">-->
    <div class="panel panel-primary" style="border-color: #464646;">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="border-color: #BBBBBB; height: 35px; padding-top: 3px;">
            <div style="float: left; margin-top: 5px;">Line Chart</div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
            <div>
                <canvas id="myChart" width="325" height="325"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--/div>-->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#myChart` is not present in the DOM when you're trying to initialize the chart. Try with `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`.

Anyhow, it loook like you're not initializing the chart from the controller once the data is populated, like you should do.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I had to use the [hidden] property since I'm developing in Angular 2. So [hidden]="!chartData"

Comment: @Roka545 I had the same problem as you, if you don't say that 
I would not have been able to find the solution, thanks! Angular 6 has the same problem, just you need use the directive [hidden].

Answer (score 0):

you have to create the Chart object only after the div is created, so call the function that create the Chart on the same place where you change the `chartData.length` instead of calling it right after the component is created