# Chart issues with *ngIf in angular 2

Tags: angular, highcharts

I was trying to display a chart after loading the data. So I implemented a conditional div rendering using *ngIf where the div area will be loaded on successful data retrieval. I had a couple of highcharts in this div which were not loading then.

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486799/chart-js-chart-does-not-display-when-inside-an-ngif) which says that we cannot use `ngIf` for charts in angular 2. But when I avoid using `ngIf` and use `ngShow`/`ng-show`/`ngCloak`, the charts are loading, but the data in the page are not loaded.

```
<div class=title-bar *ngIf="isLoaded">
  <div class=container><a class=btn-back href=temp.html>Back</a>
    <p class=title>{{project.name}}</p>
    <div class=col-sm-6>
      <div id='chart-2'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here, I was trying to load the chart into id=`chart-2`. When I don't use *ngIf, the chart is loaded, but not `project` object. Is there another alternative to implement the functionality here?

Comment: Why is `project` not loading? does it throw an error like project is undefined at that point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had fixed this issue using a work around. Posting it here so that anyone can use it in the future.

I am using the class 'invisible' (display:none;) when `isLoaded=false`.

```
<div class="tabs {{isLoaded? '': 'invisible'}}">
  <div class=container><a class=btn-back href=temp.html>Back</a>
    <p class=title>{{project.name}}</p>
    <div class=col-sm-6>
      <div id='chart-2'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the way to avoid the problem with Highcharts inside `ngIf` block, but if when you remove the `ngIf` the charts are loading, there's a simple solution for the `project.name` part.

Angular templates have a feature called [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator), which makes sure values are only interpolated when they are available.
You can use `<p class=title>{{project?.name}}</p>` which protects you from `project` being undefined before it's loaded.

Comment: It works. Although not the best solution as I wanted to hide the div itself till the data is loaded. (there are more divs like above and for 2 seconds all of them are empty now) :-) Any idea about that?